# Types of optional and default parameters in typescript

Tags: typescript

Let's say I'm making a function which can return the only parameter itself, in javascript it will be like:

```
function returnItself(x) {
  return x;
}
```

And I also want to keep the type of parameter unchanged, and make the parameter optional, so I wrote:

```
function returnItself<T>(x?: T) {
  return x;
}
```

But the results are...

```
var a1 = returnItself("foo");
type A1 = typeof a1; // expect A1 to be "string", but it's "string | undefined".
var a2 = returnItself();
type A2 = typeof a2; // expect A2 to be "undefined", but it's "{} | undefined".
```

I tried to change the optional parameter to a default value:

```
function returnItself<T extends any>(x: T = 0 as number) {
  return x; // if x is not given it should return number 0;
}
```

But even got an compiler error:

```
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'T'.
```

What would be the right way to write this?

***** EDIT ****

In this case:

```
function returnItself<T>(x?: T) {
  return x;
}
var a1 = returnItself(undefined); // a1 = undefined. ok
var a2 = returnItself(); // a2 = undefined. ok
type A1 = typeof a1; // type A1 = undefined. ok
type A2 = typeof a2; // type A2 = {} | undefined. ???
```

If I pass undefined as argument clearly, Typescript can infer the return type correctly.

However when I just leave the argument not given, I expect the same result (and type) with the above one, but their result type is not the same.

I believe `returnItself()` and `returnItself(undefined)` should have the same behaviour, maybe I'm wrong?

======
After 2 years I find the best answer:

```
function returnItself<T = undefined>(x?: T): T {
  return x as T;
}
```

Comment: You can't set a default of type `number` to a parameter of type `T`. Since types are erased at runtime, you can't really make a runtime decision (ie which default to assign to `x` based on `T`)

Answer (score 0):

optional means it can be `undefined` or `null`. So the returning type is correct.

If you dont want it to be null then simply use

```
function returnItself<T>(x: T) {
  return x;
}
```

also `T` is generic type which means it can be anything. You cannot force it to be `number`

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign `number` to `T` because it doesn't make sense to the compiler. Basically, `T` is a generic type and you're using it here as a variable. That means a user who calls this function can say what type `T` should be at runtime:

```
const a1 = returnItself<number>(9)
```

So when you assign `number` to `T` typescript complains because it doesn't know what `T` is yet. If you wanna work with optional values in `TypeScript` I suggest getting in the habit of explicitly checking if that value exists in the function body. The following will pass all your tests:

```
function returnItself<T>(x?: T) {
  if (x) return x
  else return 0 //or whatever other value you want as a default case
}
```

Comment: I agree, though I feel that what OP is looking for from this function is also a bit confusing so I did the best I could with my limited understanding. I'm happy to hear any criticisms or explanations as to why I'm wrong though

Comment: It's not really clear to me what the intent is either. I believe he wants a default, based on `T`, which is not possible without some other parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This would be your simplest code

```
function returnItself<T>(x?: T) {
  return x as T;
}
```